# Basket analysis with Spark FP-Growth

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, market-basket-analysis

Hy,

I'm trying to build a recommendation basket analysis with Spark using FP-Growth algorithm

I have these transactions

```
val transactions = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  Array("Tuna", "Banana", "Strawberry"),
  Array("Melon", "Milk", "Bread", "Strawberry"),
  Array("Melon", "Kiwi", "Bread"),
  Array("Bread", "Banana", "Strawberry"),
  Array("Milk", "Tuna", "Tomato"),
  Array("Pepper", "Melon", "Tomato"),
  Array("Milk", "Strawberry", "Kiwi"),
  Array("Kiwi", "Banana", "Tuna"),
  Array("Pepper", "Melon")
))
```

Now I want *"frequent item"*

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.AssociationRules
import org.apache.spark.mllib.fpm.FPGrowth.FreqItemset

val freqItemsets = transactions
  .flatMap(xs => 
    (xs.combinations(1) ++ xs.combinations(2)).map(x => (x.toList, 1L))
  )
  .reduceByKey(_ + _)
  .map{case (xs, cnt) => new FreqItemset(xs.toArray, cnt)}

val ar = new AssociationRules()
  .setMinConfidence(0.4)

val results = ar.run(freqItemsets)
```

Finally I'm using association rules to get the "rules"

```
results.collect().foreach { rule =>
  println("[" + rule.antecedent.mkString(",")
    + "=>"
    + rule.consequent.mkString(",") + "]," + rule.confidence)
}
```

Everything Ok until now, but next I want to give recommendation for each transaction... There are any easy way to do that? because my scala is very bad

In R I do something like this

```
baskets=function(x){
  rulesMatchLHS = is.subset(rules@lhs,x)
  suitableRules =  rulesMatchLHS & !(is.subset(rules@rhs,x))
  order.rules = sort(rules[suitableRules], by = "lift")
}

results = sapply(1:length(trans), function(x) baskets(trans[x]))
```

thanks for your time

Comment: I'm not actually sure what you are asking about.

Comment: Example, for basket 1 ("Tuna", "Banana", "Strawberry"), what product I recommend for this client?

Answer (score 0):

Well, after you generated your rules, they will look like something like this:
lhs => rhs (confidence), or in more details for example:

("tuna", "banana") => ("strawberry") (confidence)

Now you are going to have a list of these rules starting from a minimum confidence. After this you want to use the list of rules to make predictions for certain baskets, o new basket coming.

You are going to need to find the rules that best match the items in the new basket, certain value or score for that matching, lets say a new basket with ("tuna","banana") will perfectly match the rule above (match with the left side of the rule) but if less items match the score should be lower, you can set a minimum score as well to trigger a recommendation, once you get a match to a rule then recommend the right side items of the rules.

I hope this is clear,you have everything you need to do that on the code you provided.